# Uncaught exception 'No_Result_Exception' with message 'No results'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with this codeigniter script called Crysandrea, anyways everything was going smoothly until I tried out the trading system.

Here is the error.

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'No_Result_Exception' with message 'No results' in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\core\CRYS_Model.php:97
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\application\core\CRYS_Model.php(190):
>   CRYS_Model->_process_result(Object(CI_DB_mysql_result), 1) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\trades.php(535):
>   CRYS_Composite_Model->findRelation('3', '1', '*', Array) #2 [internal
>   function]: Trades->accept_trade('2') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(203):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\application\core\CRYS_Model.php on line 97

Here's the code for CRYS_Model.php

```
protected function _process_result(&$result, $limit=1) {
        if (!$result->result_array())
            throw new No_Result_Exception();
        if ($limit === 1)
            return $result->row(0, static::$INNER_MODEL);
        else
            return $result->result(static::$INNER_MODEL);
}
```

If you need anything, please say so!